# TweenLite does not work with object

Tags: actionscript-3

I got the following problem:

I have an object called tempScore for my game.

This object is blitted to the canvas by a renderer via the copyPixels method. The object is NOT a display object. It's a Score-object (self made). The Score-object extends an object called BasicBlitArrayObject. The BasicBlitArrayObject extends an EventDispatcher (therefore no display object).

I tried to apply several different TweenLite-plugins to my tempScore-object (i.e. TransformAroundCenter, colorMatrixFilter, etc.). But nothing happens. Absolutely nothing.

Sometimes I get error messages (when a plugin requires a display object and my object is NOT a display object). So far so good.

According to Greensock (maker of Tweenlite) his engine can tween ANY numeric property of ANY object. So when a plugin like TransformAroundCenter requires a display object for tweening I have to modify the plugin to get it working for my non-display object (tempScore). Currently I can't do that because it's way too hard for me.

My game rests upon this code:
http://www.8bitrocket.com/book/ch11_blastermines.zip

Try to apply TweenLite with an object called tempMine inside the game class BlasterMines. It won't work. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greensock's claim is correct, in it's exactness.  *You can tween any numeric property of any object.* This statement does not include the application of plugin features.

The reason that the TransformAroundCenter and ColorMatrixFilter plugins don't work for you is that they each utilise some property or method of `DisplayObject`.  In the case of transformAroundCenter that's `DisplayObject.localToGlobal()` and for ColorMatrixFiler it's `DisplayObject.filters`.

I have to ask why you're applying these plugins to something that is not a display object?  In blitting (as it applies to AS3), the basic idea is that you read an area from a sprite sheet to a BitmapData object, which in turn you write to a Bitmap object on the stage.  Both BitmapData and Bitmap extend DisplayObject, which is what you need.  For higher compatibility you should target the Bitmap object that is actually on the stage, TransformAroundCenter will not work correctly with an object that is not on the stage.

For a better answer you will have to post some code, and possibly a screenshot from a debugger like [Monster Debugger 3](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) which shows your expanded display tree.